# WCF security implementation for multiple platforms on mobile devices

Tags: c#, wcf, security, rest, mobile

We currently have a whole bunch of WCF REST services that are exposed to the internet. Multiple mobile devices consume these services (iOS, Android, Symbian, etc.) as well as an array of cross-platform solutions.

The very first thing we did was ensure that everything runs over SSL. However I need to ensure that the devices who call these REST services are authenticated to do so. For example if I have a RetrieveBalance POST that takes the ID number of the person in the body, ANYBODY can call this method with other ID numbers and get their balance.

I need every call to basically authenticate against a username and password/pin before (for example) retrieving the person's balance.

Is there a way in WCF REST to do something like this that would work across a variety of different platforms? My idea was to add a username and password into the header and grab it out on the server using:

```
 var username = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Username"];
 var pwd = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Password"];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Would something like this work? http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS you can use [Basic authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx) - if you host service in IIS it will be little bit more tricky to have the custom user name and password validation (default implementation expects windows accounts) but it is possible through [custom module](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/). This problem doesn't exist with self hosting the service because you can implement [custom user name password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx).

Comment: I do not intend to degrade the credibility of your answer, but I think the OP might be asking on how the client(s) in different platform can pass a username and password in a RESTful Service in WCF. Probably because some clients might not have an available config file or assembly to pass those validations in the service.

Comment: My service is hosted in IIS. I very much doubt I will be able to use any IIS modules, especially due to the varied nature of the devices connecting. The authentication will need to happen somewhere in the code behind.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona: [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is standardized process of sending credentials over HTTP - RESTful service runs over HTTP. It is just standardized way how to pass credentials in Authorization HTTP header. I expect most HTTP client APIs on different platforms already have this support implemented.

Comment: @Dylan: The custom module is running on the server side (IIS) and it is completely transparent to your client devices - they don't know about the module at all. It is just another component in request processing which is just responsible for validating credentials prior to passing request to your service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<security  mode="Transport">` then go and implement basic user/pass credential type with custom user/pass validator (no IIS module required). If you can't do it the simplest way is to have user name and password arguments added to each of your service methods and verify them on each call. Crude but should work.